# Git pull created merge commit that is not needed

Tags: git

When I was committing my work to branch `A` and pushed to repo, git complained that I needed to update my project. I updated my project via `git pull` and there was an automatic merge done. Now there are two commits after the merge: one commit was for my changes and the other commit was from the automatic merge after the `git pull`.

I noticed that the merge commit already had all the changes that was already reflected in the repo so why does git create another commit specifically for that merge when all the changes are already reflected? Is there a way to remove that merge commit before I push? It makes things unnecessary complicated. That merge commit is essentially useless.

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, `git pull` *means* `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely—do the two commands separately. In your case you want fetch, then rebase. Note, by the way, that by default rebase will copy your commit but ditch the merge, so you can fix your existing situation using `git rebase`.

Comment: These days I just do `git reset origin/A` to avoid the headache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The merge incorporates your local changes with the changes that were fetched from the server.  If you don't have local changes, or if no new changes are fetched from the server, then no merge commit is created.  That may or may not be how you want to reflect the integration of changes - there are other options which you can set via configuration or command-line options - but it does have to happen somehow.

In particular, what I mean is - you indicated that all changes in the repo were already accounted for without the merge commit.  But there must be commits that were fetched from the remote, that weren't already in your local repo - otherwise there would be no merge commit.  If you graph the history of the merge commit, you should see something like

```
             R -- S
            /      \
x -- x -- O -- A -- M
```

where `A` is your local commit, `O` is the commit you'd previously fetched from the remote, and `R` and `S` are commits fetched from the remote when you pulled (also based at `O`).  You can see what `M` is doing by (a) examining `R` and `S`, or (b) `diff`ing `M` against `A`.

(One potentially confusing special case, the *net* result of the changes from the server could be "no change".  For example, maybe someone committed `R` but then reverted `R` and committed that as `S`.  The resulting merge would have no effect, but git still has to do it to ensure that branches only move forward with each push.)

Anyway, this is the default behavior because it's the simplest and safest way to incorporate the remote changes into your local branch.  But it's not the only way.  You can ask git to `rebase` your local branch onto the remote branch instead.  Then you'd get

```
x -- x -- O -- R -- S -- A'
```

For simple workflows this works reasonably, and it tends to comply with the biggest rule of rebasing - which is (roughly) that it avoids rewriting commits that have already been shared.

It does have costs and risks, though.  From the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config under `pull.rebase`:

> NOTE: this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless you understand the implications (see git-rebase[1] for details).

Your commit is replaced by `A'`, which has not yet passed any unit tests.  That alone isn't so bad - in the "merge" case, `M` hadn't yet passed any tests either.  But if you have a more complex local history, it's possible that *many* commits will have been rewritten.  So you could end up with many untested commits, and pushing untested commits can make life harder down the road (e.g. if you want to use `bisect` to find the commit that introduced a bug).

Also, further configuration may be needed to determine how merge commits in your local history should be handled.

Still, for some workflows - such as if you pull often and expect you will not have a large or complicated local history - the benefits may outweigh the costs; and in that case you can either

```
git pull --rebase
```

or set this as your default by saying

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Answer (score 6):

To avoid creating redundant merge commits when pulling you should use `git pull --rebase`. You can execute it in your current situation as well to get rid of the merge commit.

Comment: Hmm I see. I noticed that git needs to reevaluate their defaults. `git pull --rebase` should be the default pull instead of git pull.

Comment: @Robin - If you want `--rebase` to be the default behavior, you can set this in your git configuration.  Whether `--rebase` is a good idea depends on the workflow; and the degree to which things can get messed up is greater if you use `--rebase` when you shouldn't than if you don't use it when you should; and using `--rebase` generally entails more work (including potentially more involved conflict resolution).  So the assertion that git should make `--rebase` the overall default is incorrect.

Comment: If you've got 30 commits and you do a rebase and hit major conflicts on the first commit, then you're probably going to have to resolve conflicts for the remaining 29 commits... one... at... a... dang... time. I love me a good rebase, but sometimes merge is the most sane thing to do.