# Why does git do a merge every time I pull to my web host?

Tags: git

Lately, every time I want to pull changes to my web host, git prompts me to enter a merge message.  I am not sure how I got in this situation.  Why do I have to merge every time I pull?

My local branch is master. The branch on my web host is also master.

If I do the usual steps I have always done...

1. Make change on local. Git add. Git commit. Push.
2. SSH into web host. Navigate to project directory.  Git pull.

...why am I then prompted to merge?

Note: I am not asking how to avoid entering a merge message.  I am asking why I have to merge at all, and how do I get out of this situation.

Comment: A merge is required only when a fast-forward isn't possible -- meaning that you have commits on the local branch that aren't in the remote one. If you make your local branch match the state the remote one was in _before the newly-added changes took place_ (or _any_ state in that commit's history), a merge will no longer be mandatory.

Comment: ...if your "web host" is your production server, you probably shouldn't be doing a `git pull` at all (since that pull is preserving changes that are local to that production server -- but a production server _shouldn't have_ local changes), and should be doing a hard reset instead.

Comment: Consider doing something like `git diff HEAD origin/master` (making assumptions about your remote and branch naming conventions; adjust to fit) to see exactly what's different. (It's possible to have two different commits with identical code, so that diff _could_ come back empty -- if it does, that's a good thing, because it means you can switch to the `reset` workflow seamlessly).

Comment: Git `pull` always performs a merge. It's essentially a composite of `fetch` and `merge` from the remote branch. Git will only ask for a merge 'comment' if they have a different history. So it might be that you are trying to pull when you are ahead of the branch you're trying to merge from? Not sure tho!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pull created merge commit that is not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447580/git-pull-created-merge-commit-that-is-not-needed)

Comment: BTW, with my security hat on, the whole idea of having a production host's filesystem _even be writable at all_ gives me the heebies a bit; if you can do a `git pull` there, someone else can edit your files to inject malware or whatnot. Stateless, read-only systems -- where moving to a new software build or updating packages means booting into a different read-only filesystem -- are considerably more sound.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's a bit off topic, but also likely confusing/FUD to inexperienced readers. I think you're conflating file permissions required to run git operations (hopefully only a privileged user), permissions to source code a runtime (read only, one would hope) and implicitly permissions to other writable directories (like /tmp). Using `git pull` to 'deploy' a new version of an app does not in and of itself imply any security risk in the absence of other info/evidence.

Comment: @AD7six, if I meant it to be on-topic, it'd be part of the answer, not a comment. That said, a system where _even a privileged user_ can change things is less secure than one that can't be changed at all. Trusting someone is worse than trusting no-one. (Yes, this means I think _basically everyone_ is doing it wrong). If a privileged user can change things, an attacker who improperly gained privileges can change things too; better to have systems you swap out with new ones instead of changing them in-place at all.

Comment: @AD7six, ...take a look at NixOS as an example of an operating system where all your software comes from a content-hashed read-only store, and writable things are stored on tmpfs. (Sure, a typical NixOS deployment will still let root append new hash-addressed items to that store to add additional software, and then change the active set to point to a new root hash, but folks aren't forced to build typical deployments; combine that with the tools Google has built to make ChromeOS root filesystems read-only and one gets a true RO system w/ cryptographic proof that sw isn't tampered with).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy heading off on a weird tangent :) but - `Yes, this means I think basically everyone is doing it wrong` - do you think comments on a git question are the right place to push for your favored application security solution? /end

Comment: @AD7six, ...I think quick asides with at least _some_ reasonable association with the context of the question (as, here, being associated with "how do we update production servers' code?") are something comments are suited for; it's only when it turns into a longer conversation (as happened here in responding to objections) that it's more clearly inappropriate. /end, indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you haven't disabled default fast-forward behavior, this implies that there are commits in your web host's history that *aren't* in the history of your development branch.

git can skip needing to create a merge commit during a merge by doing a fast-forward<sup>[1]</sup> only when the current state is somewhere in the history of the new state. If there's code that was checked in *directly on your web server*, or there was something like a `git rebase` that changed history, that assumption can cease to be true.

If you want to make your production web server's code exactly match what's in git, *don't use `pull` at all* -- the correct tool to use in this situation is `git reset --hard` instead.

---

<sup>[1] -`pull` *always* does a merge of some kind -- `fetch` + `merge` is what `pull` *means* in git terms -- but when it's a fast-forward merge that makes it much closer to invisible.</sup>

Comment: (Community Wiki because I'd be astonished if this wasn't a duplicate of something already asked-and-answered elsewhere in the knowledge base).

Comment: "commits in your web host's history that aren't in the history of your development branch".  That's it. I have a `master` branch & a `logo` branch in both the local git history and the git history at my host. However, the `logo` branch contains two commits at my host that I don't have locally. I don't understand the suggestion to use `git reset --hard` here. This has no effect because the production code already matches the latest git commit on production. The prod code won't differ from the latest commit until I pull a new commit. I tried `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard`. No effect.

Comment: To clarify, `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard` has no effect even though there is a new commit in the repo that I want to pull/fetch to the host.

Comment: @arnoldbird, you need to pass the name of the remote branch (that you want your working tree and current branch pointer to match) to `git reset --hard`. So something like `git reset --hard origin/master`, if you just did `git fetch origin` and your branch is `master`.

Comment: Looks like `git reset --hard origin/master` is indeed what I needed. That seems to also have had the effect of removing the merges from the git log. And it removed the `logo` branch from the git project on the web host... which is fine. I've never used `git reset` this way. In the past I've always used it with a commit hash.

Comment: Just to circle back, if I remember correctly, this solution didn't actually work for me.  It had the effect of removing a commit (and a file) that I needed.  It was a simple commit, so I just re-did it and committed again.

Comment: It works when "working" consists of making your local tree exactly match the remote one. If you don't want them to match, you _need_ the merge commits. If you want to find the changes made in the local tree, create a new commit that contains only them, and add that to the remote tree, that's perfectly doable, but it's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally disabled your fast-forwarding, which as the other commenter suggested, will require you to merge commit when pulling. To re-enable, simply run:

```
git config pull.ff true
```